# How to use a shared folder on Windows Server 2016 and Amazon AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon AWS EC2(Windows 2016 64bit) and want to access to shared folders on it from my laptop(Windows 10 64bit). I configured Security Group policy and opened all traffic and port range(I tried using Ping on my laptop to the instance and it worked).

Then I made a folder and set its properties(Network File and Folder Sharing). The network path is `\\EC2AMAZ-SI5EFBN\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Folder`. I thought I could access to the folder from my laptop if I substitute `EC2AMAZ-SI5EFBN` with the instance's `IP address`, but it doesn't work and says that it cannot find it. It works find if I do the same with a computer that's in the same local network. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [create a file gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/create-gateway-file.html). You should then create a NFS or SMB [file share](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/GettingStartedCreateFileShare.html) and configure your Windows or Mac clients to [access the files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/getting-started-use-fileshare.html).

You can copy files and folders to your mapped drive. The files automatically upload to your Amazon S3 bucket.

For additional info see [AWS File gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/create-file-gateway.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have read the web pages and according to what I have understood, it seems I need to use S3 service to map a network drive(folder) in my EC2 instance, is it right?

Comment: Yes. The gateway uses S3 as the storage area for shared file (using cache). S3 also gives you the endpoints that you can use for access from client machines. Use IAM roles for EC2 to S3 access, and set up security groups to limit access to S3 from external clients.

Comment: D.Thank you for your detailed answer. I don't understand why Amazon has made it complicated and one has to use two different services even when simply mapping network drives.

Comment: It gets complicated every time you want to access resources in another network.  For external devices to gain access to files in your network, you need to use some kind of gateway to control and secure the traffic. You also have the option to VPN into that network to gain visibility into instances running in your virtual private cloud. It gets a bit more complicated when you run your instances in private subnets that would require routing tables and NAT servers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need necessarily a Storage Gateway. That requires an xlarge instance that is not free-tier eligible. 
All you have to do is install the AWS CLI (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) in your EC2 instance. 
Then you create an s3 bucket (free) on AWS s3. Open Powershell from your EC2 instance and type aws configure . You'll have to input your ID key and your secret key (only the first time). These are found in AWS account, My security credentials.

Then type aws s3 sync C:\mylocalfolder s3://mys3bucket

Save this command on a .bat file and have task scheduler run it every 10 minutes. This command copies the contents of the EC2 folder you want to share into the s3 bucket.
In the .bat file the command you have to put the whole path of aws.exe like this:
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" s3 sync C:\EC2localfolder s3://mys3bucket

Then you go to your laptop and do the same, this time syncing the bucket to another folder like this:
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws.exe" s3 sync s3://mys3bucket C:\laptoplocalfolder

you'll have to make your bucket public or make some bucket policy that white lists the public IP of the machine you want to access the data from.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable "Netbios" on your VPN interface(s).  Otherwise, you can see the share you create, but you won't be able to authenticate and access it from the LAN node.